# Is there a way to consolidate jQuery functions which do the same thing but on different classes and ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The code I have is as follows:

```
 $('.contact_btn').click(function(){
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
    }, 1000);

});

$('.insurance_btn').click(function(){
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#insuranceFormTop").offset().top
    }, 1000);

});

$('.bmw_btn').click(function(){
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bmwContactTop").offset().top
    }, 1000);

});
```

Is there a way to make just one function which takes in the class and acts on the respective id.

Comment: Just make a function that takes the class and the id, and call it thrice with the respective pairs.

Comment: @Berji essentially this is what i want to do but i am very new to jQuery and am having a lot of trouble achieving this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's just a javascript function that executes javascript code (that uses the jQuery library).

Comment: @Bergi shamefully, i have no idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: Take the repeated code, place it inside a `function name(){ … }`, then add parameters for those little things that are different in each repetition and use those variables instead of the values. Then call that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function simplefunction(classname,id){
    $('.'+classname).click(function(){
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
        }, 1000);

    });
    }


<div class="relevant_button" id="respective_I‌D" onclick="simplefunction(this.getAttribute('class'),this.id)">
```

Comment: that's the one I tried. check the comment I left in the answer below if that helps. I really appreciate your help in this I can see this answer is really close to what I want to achieve.

Comment: lol that looks so funny. could you edit it so that it uses the dosomething function?

Comment: this really helped thank you very much for your help

Comment: padhwal i tried using this function and its not working.  I forgot to save the js file before trying the function out and what i tested was my original function from before. i have another function attached to the onclick and the console throws a not defined error on the  scroll_to_the_top_of_the_respective_id_and_close_th‌​e_modal function

Comment: change function name from such a tedious one to something simple and look at the edited code,pass the id along with the class.

Comment: I have done exactly that and I keep getting the not defined error

Comment: that is because you must be calling your function before defining it keep your function defintion before calling it

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do like this

```
$('.contact_btn').click(function(){
    animate('contact');
});

function animate(id) {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

It will work for you.

Comment: if I do it this way it still means I have to write the code three times. I don't want to have to do that. I'm in need of a code that takes in the divs class and acts upon that. so for example. <div class="relevant_button" onclick="scroll_to_the_top_of_the_respective_id_and_close_the_modal(respective_ID)">